# Last Non-blank cell across columns

Tags: r

I am trying to execute a code in R which should give me two things which are

1. if all the three cells are blank...it should output as Blank (row-wise across columns)
2. if one of the cells have values, the output should be the value of last non-blank cell 
   [image]

the data:

```
PR1 PR2 PR3 Required Output

P1  P2      P2
P1  P2  P3  P3
    P2  P4  P4
    P3      P3
P2          P2
```

I have tried this:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) tail(na.omit(x), 1))
```

But it doesnt fulfill the first requirement.

Any help in this regard would be great. Thanks

Comment: What does your data actually look like? There's no way to decipher it from what you have above.

Comment: I have attached a snapshot of the data. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
apply(data, 1, function(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) == 3, "", tail(na.omit(x), 1)))
```

Comment: Replace `3` with `ncol(data)` and  `""` with `NA` and you have a more general solution.  Nice.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses `is.na` to check for NA or not, `cumsum` to created a cumulative number of NA's up to then, and `which.max` to find the last non NA value:

```
apply(pr_data, 1, 
    function(row_data) row_data[which.max(cumsum(!is.na(row_data)))])
```

For example on one row (makes the code seems less like black magic..):

```
row_data = pr_data[5,]
#    pr1 pr2  pr3
# 5 <NA>  p3 <NA>
!is.na(row_data)
#     pr1  pr2   pr3
# 5 FALSE TRUE FALSE
cumsum(!is.na(row_data))
# [1] 0 1 1
which.max(cumsum(!is.na(row_data)))
# Returns the first occurence of the max value, which is the last non-NA value
row_data[which.max(cumsum(!is.na(row_data)))]
# The actual value
#   pr2
# 5  p3
```

Comment: Slick solution.  Didn't think to use `which.max` and `cumsum` in this way.

Comment: Thanks. But I still would like to have a more intuitive solution, still looks too much like black magic...

Comment: @PaulHiemstra  could you please delete your comment here: 
 http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/106/2012/9/6/0-24     about my question. Or at least delete the path to the file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R method that uses `max.col` to select the final position, `rowSums` and `==` to check if all elements in the row are NA, and finally matrix subsetting.

```
# construct logical matrix of NA positions since it is (sort of) used twice
naMat <- is.na(pr_data)
# locate final non-NA position for each row
myOut <- max.col(!naMat, ties.method = "last")
# set NA to positions where all elements in row are NA
is.na(myOut) <- rowSums(naMat) == ncol(pr_data)
# use matrix to select desired elements from original data.frame
pr_data$out <- pr_data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(pr_data)), myOut)]
```

This returns

```
pr_data
   pr1  pr2  pr3  out
1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2   p1   p2 <NA>   p2
3   p1   p2   p3   p3
4 <NA>   p2   p4   p4
5 <NA>   p3 <NA>   p3
6   p2 <NA> <NA>   p2
```

Answer (score 0):

A chained `ifelse` is one way to do it....

```
# Creating data set
pr1 <- as.character(c(NA, 'p1', 'p1', NA, NA, 'p2'))
pr2 <- as.character(c(NA, 'p2', 'p2', 'p2', 'p3', NA))
pr3 <- as.character(c(NA, NA, 'p3', 'p4', NA, NA))
pr_data <- data.frame(pr1, pr2, pr3)
pr_data <- data.frame(lapply(pr_data, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(pr_data)

# Actual solution
pr_data$required_output <- ifelse(!is.na(pr_data$pr3), 
                                  pr_data$pr3, 
                                  ifelse(!is.na(pr_data$pr2), 
                                         pr_data$pr2, 
                                         pr_data$pr1))
```

Comment: It probably works, but it is not a robust solution. If you want to do this approach with more than three columns, you need to rewrite the code.

Comment: That's a fair point, though I'm not sure why you'd say "probably works" since my solution DOES produce the desired output as the question is framed.  Without knowing the actual specifics of his data, neither of us know if this is efficient.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: I should indeed drop the probably as you've shown the code works,you are right.